# Filtering tracks by streamable = true in Soundcloud

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to use the javascript SDK for Soundcloud to return a list of tracks that are streamable.

My question is: How do I filter search results for only streamable songs using the javascript SDK?

Here is an example that will return songs that are not streamable:

```
SC.get('/tracks', {q: 'mat zo', filter: 'streamable'}).then(function (tracks) { 
    console.log(tracks); 
});
```

Here is what the request comes out to be:

> api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=mat+zo&filter=streamable&format=json&client_id=[XXX]

I noticed that the first track in this response has streamable=false.
 
snippet of the response:

> ...
>       streamable: false
>       tag_list: "Remix Mat Zo Burn Ellie Goulding"
>       title: "Burn (Mat Zo Remix)"
>       track_type: ""
>       ...

Looking at the Soundcloud SDK documentation I don't see a way to do this as the 'filter' query parameter only accepts '(all, public, private)'.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks
(I am looking at the Filters)

same unanswered question:
stackoverflow.com/questions/23791711/filtering-tracks-by-streamable-in-soundcloud

Thanks in advance, this is my first question. I can provide more of my code upon request.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to accomplish it by altering the request to the Soundcloud SDK, or by dealing with the returned data from the request?

Comment: I am asking how to alter the request made to the server to only give me a response of streamable=true songs. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (documented) filter for the streamable property on the API. You can however easily filter out the unstreamable tracks yourself:

```
SC.get('/tracks', {q: 'mat zo'}).then(function (tracks) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        if(!(tracks[i].streamable)) {           
        tracks.splice(i,1);
      } 
    }
    console.log(tracks); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hartger. I was hoping that there was a way to make the server do it but I can do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell without having a token to test. However, the [documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search) around "Search"  appears to imply that sounds can be filtered by property directly:

> Some resource types, such as sounds, can be filtered by fields like license, duration or tag_list.

```
  // find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
SC.get('/tracks', {
  q: 'buskers', license: 'cc-by-sa'
}).then(function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

In your case, you should replace license with streamable and 'cc-by-sa' with 'true'.

Comment: I tried that and got the same json response back as my first example. :(
`
SC.get('/tracks', {q: 'mat zo', streamable: true}).then(function (tracks) {
console.log(tracks);
});
stream_url: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/104236584/stream"
streamable: false
tag_list: "Remix Mat Zo Burn Ellie Goulding"
title: "Burn (Mat Zo Remix)"
track_type: ""`

Comment: Here is a client id to play with: 429600260189ef2f5faf0ae09ea502f7